# Given polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. If $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are roots of $q(x)$, then find the value of $p(z_1)+p(z_2) +p(z_3) +p(z_4)$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^6-x^5-x^3-x^2-x$ and $q(x)=x^4-x^3-x^2-1$. If $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are roots of $q(x)$, then find the value of $p(z_1)+p(z_2) +p(z_3) +p(z_4)$.

**My attempt:**
Dividing $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ gives
$$p(x)=(x^2+1) \cdot q(x) +(x^2-x+1)$$
So, if $z$ is a root of $q(x)$ then
$$p(z) = z^2-z+1$$

I also know that $-1$ is a root of $q(x)$. But idk how to get the value of $p(x)$ for the other roots. Any help?

Comment: So you need $\sum_{i = 1}^4 {z_i^2 }  - \sum_{i = 1}^4 {z_i }  + 4$. Do you know [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)?

Comment: Ah, I see. I know about it. Thanks.